# VueJS - Props Validation passed by type vs value

Tags: vue.js, validation, vue-props

```
defineProps({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
});
```

```
const props = defineProps({
  firstName: String
})
```

I just want to ask simple question, in the first code it passes an `object` and give it the appropriate validations, in the second it just does the validation `string` as expected value for the `firstName`, so what are the difference between these 2 samples of code ? is it that at the first code you can define multiple validations while you can't in the second block ? is that the only difference ? thanks

Comment: It's the same. Just a shorter syntax..

Comment: just read the docs for props: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all the props options

```js
defineProps({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validator(value) {
      // The value must match one of these strings
      return ['success', 'warning', 'danger'].includes(value)
    },
    default: 'success'
  },
});
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?